# get the value of JSON parameter c#

Tags: c#, jsonparser

I'm trying to get the id parameter from the json below without success, using c#. It's a double array (users/warings)

```
JSON:
contents = "{\"users\":[{\"id\":64,\"username\":\"100146\",\"firstname\":\"NAME\",\"lastname\":\"LASTNAME PROFILI\",\"department\":\"\",\"firstaccess\":0,\"lastaccess\":0"}],\"warnings\":[]}"
```

this is what I tried

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
object obj1 = serializer.DeserializeObject(contents);
object obj2 = obj1["users"];
string id = obj2["id"];
```

I get an error in obj2.
I don't want to create a class to parse the JSON into, just extract the id value from the 'users' array is enough

thanks for your time!

Comment: What's the error you get? Some basic info is helpful

Comment: the error is 'Error 10 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object' and it appears on the 'object obj2 = obj1["users"];' line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Newtwonsoft for this:

```
var json = "{\"users\":[{\"id\":64,\"username\":\"100146\",\"firstname\":\"NAME\",\"lastname\":\"LASTNAME PROFILI\",\"department\":\"\",\"firstaccess\":0,\"lastaccess\":0}],\"warnings\":[]}";

dynamic data = JObject.Parse(json);

var id = data.users[0].id;
```

Comment: downloading newtonsoft.. back soon to mark as answer if fits...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the dynamic rather than object type:

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{\"users\":[{\"id\":64,\"username\":\"100146\",\"firstname\":\"NAME\",\"lastname\":\"LASTNAME PROFILI\",\"department\":\"\",\"firstaccess\":0,\"lastaccess\":0"}],\"warnings\":[]}");

var usersCount = d.users.Count;
var warningsCount = d.warnings.Count;

var id = d.users[0].id;
```

Comment: hi thiago, I'll give a try on that, didn't know about Newtwonsoft

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried but try using object1["users"]["id"]

Comment: hi urvil, I've tried this and got some errors, the fizx was using the json.net

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
            JObject obj = JObject.Parse(response);

            paymentId = (string)obj["Id"];
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**